# React function components: is this right approach to problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
export default function loginvia(loginmethod: string) {
    const [state, setstate] = useState(loginmethod);
    function login() {
        body
    }
    function oauth() {
        body
        login()
    }
    function magic_link() {
       body
       login()
     }
     return eval(state);
}

import loginvia from "./filename";

const authlogin = loginvia("oauth");
authlogin();
```

I need to use child login function as helper function in different login methods and I can't write login function outside main function body because of hooks and mutations I am using. I used `eval` in return to call string as function. I can import parent function and use whichever login method for login. Is this right approach to solve this problem or if not then please suggest me one?

Comment: what about a mapping table, conditions or switch? `switch(loginmethod){ case "oauth": ...; case "magic_link": ... }` eval is the worst possible approach here.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "child" and "parent" functions. Where are those "*hooks and mutations*" you are using?

Comment: No, you absolutely should not use `eval`.

Comment: If `loginvia` is meant to be a hook, it should be named `useLoginVia` by convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you need state here, instead of eval I would just use a simple object lookup to the methods.

And since you are using Typescript I would add some typing here to make things a bit nicer.

eg.

```
type LoginMethods = 'oauth' | 'magic_link';

export default function useLoginvia(loginmethod: LoginMethods) {
    function login() {
    }
    function oauth() {
        login()
    }
    function magic_link() {
       login()
    }
    const loginMethods:Record<LoginMethods, () => void> = {
        magic_link,
        oauth
    }
    return loginMethods[loginmethod]
}

//import loginvia from "./filename";

const authlogin = useLoginvia("oauth");
authlogin();
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of eval is generally discouraged in JavaScript due to security risks. You can use this approach by defining separate functions for each login method within the component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function LoginVia({ loginMethod }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(loginMethod);

  const login = () => {
    console.log("Common login logic");
  };

  const oauth = () => {
    console.log("OAuth specific logic");
    login();
  };

  const magicLink = () => {
    console.log("Magic link specific logic");
    login();
  };

  const handleLogin = () => {
    switch (state) {
      case "oauth":
        oauth();
        break;
      case "magic_link":
        magicLink();
        break;
      default:
        console.error("Invalid login method");
    }
  };

  handleLogin();

  return null;
}

import LoginVia from "./LoginVia";

const authLogin = <LoginVia loginMethod="oauth" />;
```